# AJAX Contact Form - Success and Failure Message

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've gotten my form to submit via PHP but I'm struggling a bit with the AJAX. Upon submission, the error always comes up as if res is set to false rather than true. I've tried toying around with the code and searching for my own answer because I *do* want to learn, but I'm not finding what I need.

May you please point me in the right direction as to what I've done improperly?

Thank you so very much!

The code for your reference:

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function() {

    var this_form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: this_form.serialize(),
        url: 'scripts/send_email.php',
        success: function(res) {
            if(res == "true") {
                $(this_form)[0].reset();
                $(".notice").removeClass("error").text("Thank you for contacting us!").addClass("success").fadeIn("fast");
            } else {
                $(".notice").text("Please check all fields and try again.").addClass("error").fadeIn("fast");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to ask for:

```
if(res == true)
```

instead. Also a good way to avoid this kind of problems is to debug your javascript via firebug or the chrome debugger, if you are using chrome you could add this line to your code:

```
debugger;
if(res == "true")
```

and the javascript will stop there so you can inspect the variable and see what's happening. you can open it by going to "options --> tools --> developer tools --> scripts".

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your truth comparison is returning false due to the value that `res` represents.  You are checking to make sure it is a string with the value of "true".  If not, then trigger else code.

Your `success` property will only be executed if the AJAX transmission was successful.  You will want to set the comparison check to the desired output of `send_email.php`, i.e. 'Success!' or 'Failure!' to indicate the proper handling.

> **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)**
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three
>   arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to
>   the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn.

See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for additional information for handling AJAX requests in jQuery.

```
success: function(res) {
    if (res == "Success!") {
        $(this_form)[0].reset();
        $(".notice").removeClass("error").text("Thank you for contacting us!").addClass("success").fadeIn("fast");
    } else {
        $(".notice").text("Please check all fields and try again.").addClass("error").fadeIn("fast");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Let me know if you need additional assistance/explanation with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your send_email.php file, echo "success" if it succeed.

Then modify your AJAX call like so :

```
success: function(data) {
if (data == "success") {do stuff} else {do failure stuff}
}
```